# How to install i-ibus-avro in 14.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies

When trying to install ibus-avro in Ubuntu 14.04 the following results appear. What I should do?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
ibus-avro: Depends: ibus (>= 1.4.1-3ubuntu1) but is to be installed
           Depends: libibus-1.0-0 (>= 1.4.1-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: gjs (>= 1.32.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.40.1-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed
           Depends: gir1.2-gjsdbus-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Ubuntu 14.04

You're getting the unmet dependencies error message because you're trying to install the wrong package for Ubuntu 14.04. The correct package to install for Ubuntu 14.04 is *ibus-avro-trusty*. The complete instructions for installing ibus-avro-trusty in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./"
wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ibus-avro-trusty
```

If you get any dependency error, then also run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -fy
```

#### Ubuntu 16.04 and later

```
wget "https://github.com/ugcoder/avro/releases/download/v2.0/avro_2.0-1_all.deb"
sudo apt install ./avro_2.0-1_all.deb
```

If you get any dependency error, then also run the following command:

```
sudo apt install -fy
```